# weak law of large numbers with vanishing second moment but no iid assumption

Tags: probability-theory

How can I show the following?
If $(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables such that $E(X_n^2)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, then $(S_n-E(S_n))/n\to 0$ in probability,
where $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ as usual.
Basically what I am trying show is a form of Weak Law of Large numbers but instead of iid and finite second moment assumption, I have only vanishing second moment.
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Are $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ independent atleast?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following inequality: 
$$ \|S_n\|\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}[\mathsf{E}|S_n|^2]^{1/2}\le \sum_{i=1}^n\|X_i\|,
$$
$\|X_n\|^2=\mathsf{E}|X_n|^2\to0$ and Cauchy's Theorem, we have 
\begin{align}\mathsf{P}\Bigl(\Bigl|\frac{S_n-\mathsf{E}S_n}{n}\Bigr|\ge \varepsilon\Bigr)
&\le \frac{\mathsf{E}[|S_n-\mathsf{E}S_n|^2]}{n^2\varepsilon^2}\qquad(\text{by Chebychev inequality})\\ 
&\le \frac{\|S_n\|^2}{n^2\varepsilon^2}
\le\frac1{\varepsilon^2}\Bigl(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\|X_i\|\Bigr)^2\to0.\quad\text{as}\; n\to\infty.
\end{align}